# Cisco ASA IPSec - Fail to direct if a tunnel goes down

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

I've configured several IPSec tunnels for site-to-site.  I am aware of how to create multiple tunnels for redundancy but what I am unaware of is failing to direct.

Since you have to exempt interesting traffic from NAT it seems to be that if the tunnel goes down there is no way to fail to direct internet access without manually putting the NAT back.

I am not doing site-to-site but rather routing all internet traffic through a security appliance (think of zScaler)

Is there a way to automatically detect a downed tunnel and fail to wire?

Comment: I'm confused, first you say you have ipsec tunnels for site-to-site, then you say you are not doing site-to-site... can you please clarify what you are doing exactly? Maybe add the ASA config. If you *are* doing ipsec on the ASA then this is a similar or maybe duplicate question as http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35854/make-failover-for-site-to-site-vpn

Comment: @hertitu - The VPN is "technically" a site to site.  The right subnet is 192.168.1.0/24 for example and the left subnet is 0.0.0.0/0.  This is a product like zscaler that I am using for traffic monitoring and I direct all internet traffic through it.  If there is an issue with their service I would like to "fail open"

Comment: Ok then check the duplicate question - AFAIK this is not possible without adding the NAT as you said - except that you can possible automate this task using IP SLA and EEM instead of doing it manually.

Comment: @hertitu thanks.  Can you give me some example config.  Please reply as an answer so it formats correctly when I paste it in.

Comment: @hertitu - I will be sure to upvote your answer and accept so you get the points.  I made sure to accept your other one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take action automatically if tunnel is down, Then try with EEM(embedded event manager) feature in cisco with event as syslog message 'Tunnel down'